# Validate Date Entered from a Textbox Against Datepicker DateRange

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hi have a textbox datepicker. The user can select date from datepicker or enter date manually by typing on the textbox. If date is manually typed how can I validate the input if is within the date range of my date picker? Please help. For example my date picker max year is only 1995 so user is not allowed to input date such as 01/25/1996.

**HTML**

```
Date of Birth (MM/DD/YYYY):
<input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" 
name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear() - 18;
d.setFullYear(year);
$('#BirthDate').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    yearRange: '1920:' + year + '',
    defaultDate: d});

$('#BirthDate').blur(function(){
//Validate input
});
```

**JSfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/jobzky/wUpQG/

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect to me.

First u have to validate date syntax. Suppose date is a valid date. Then, u can do this.

```
  var from_date_monthfield = valid_from.split("/")[1];
  var from_date_dayfield = valid_from.split("/")[0];
  var from_date_yearfield = valid_from.split("/")[2];
```

// Above splitting depends on your date format

```
  var from_date = new Date(from_date_yearfield, from_date_monthfield-1, from_date_dayfield);

  var cur_date = new Date();
  if(!(from_date > cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() - 1))) // set date as 1995 here and your logic here
  { 
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the input element's `readonly` attribute in order to prevent a user from manually entering a date e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker minimumSize" 
name="BirthDate" id="BirthDate" readonly/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing that but that's not the behavior of my application. User is allowed to enter the date manually by typing input to the textbox. If readonly user cannot type anymore

Comment: This could be an issue with usability. Some users would rather type their dates than use a calendar datepicker.